# How do I close multiprocessing when I close the PYQT MainFrame

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a PYSide2 mainframe , and when button click I create a process name TTT,
I think when I close the mainframe the process close too , but it's not.

How should I do ?

```
class Test7(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
        ...(not important code here)...
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked)


    def btnClicked(self):
        ttt = TTT('aaa')
        ttt.deman = False
        ttt.start()


class TTT(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, name):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        print('nothing to do')

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print('abc')
            time.sleep(10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test7()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `daemon` to `True`.

> The process’s daemon flag, a Boolean value. This must be set
>   before start() is called.
>
> The initial value is inherited from the creating process.
>
> When a process exits, it attempts to terminate all of its daemonic
>   child processes.
>
> Note that a daemonic process is not allowed to create child processes.
>   Otherwise a daemonic process would leave its children orphaned if it
>   gets terminated when its parent process exits. Additionally, these are
>   not Unix daemons or services, they are normal processes that will be
>   terminated (and not joined) if non-daemonic processes have exited.

Take your snippet as an example:

```
class TTT(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, name):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        print('nothing to do')

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print('abc')
            time.sleep(10)
```